# Laravel mysqli connect 2 columns and change column name

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables that I want to connect

```
table1:
id
name
table2_id

table_2:
id
name
```

table1 is connected with table2

When I try to select table1 and the connected row from table2 it works, but because the row names id and name are the same, it overwrites the values of table1.

How can I connect table1 with table2 and get a table1 with this rows in laravel:

```
id
name
table2_id
table2_name
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you actually select the rows?

Comment: I have a function: 

public function scopetable1($query,$id){
  return $query = DB::table('table1')
  ->where('table1.id', '=', $id)
  ->leftJoin('table2', 'table1.table2_id', '=', 'table2.id')
  ->get();
}

Comment: [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships) are the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the laravel documentation regarding relationships - If you set up your models as outlined here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships you will be able to call the table2 like:

```
$result = Table1::find(1)->table2;
```

However to get the result you want you can use the `->select(` function

```
DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects

Something like this

```
public function scopetable1($query,$id){ 

    return $query = DB::table('table1')
    ->select('table1.id as id','table1.name as name','table2.id as table2_id', 'table2.name as table2_name' ) 
    ->where('table1.id', '=', $id) 
    ->leftJoin('table2', 'table1.table2_id', '=', 'table2.id') 
    ->get(); 
}
```